# check for zero bytes

Tags: c, function, fread

I have made a piece of code that checks for zeroes in blocks of 512 bytes. A problem I have is that it doesn't seem to check all bytes if I build a check in, here is the code:

```
int zerocheck(FILE *fp,unsigned long long seekpoint)
{
    int j;

    if(fseek(fp,seekpoint,SEEK_SET)==0)
    {
        char buf[seekwidth],cmp[seekwidth];

        if(fread(buf,sizeof buf,1,fp)==1)
        {
            for (j=0;j<seekwidth;j++)
            {
                printf("%i\n!!!\n",buf[j]);

                if (buf[j]!=0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 2;
}
```

the print is just there for debugging. the problem is it doesn't seem to check all bytes properly if the check for a zero is there. I can see from the print that it prints out a 1 if I have a 1! but as soon as I add the if statement after it doesn't print out the 1 and doesn't return the proper value. I have no idea how to fix it...

for the record this what is happening I have a file which I KNOW the 2nd byte is a 1. if I remove:

```
                if (buf[j]!=0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
```

it reads correctly and gives out this:

checking file for zeroes...
0
!!!
1
!!!
0

but if the if statement is included this is the output:
checking file for zeroes...
0
!!!
0
!!!
0

the printing is not really the issue but it is important the every byte get checked...

Comment: Is this `seekwidth` a global variable?

Comment: yes, i could make it a local var in the main but than I have to pass another variable into it. I use seekwidth in both the function and the main

Comment: If `seekwidth` is a `const` or `#define`, convention is to capitalize it: `SEEK_WIDTH`.

Comment: OK. That mean it is a macro or defined globally, right?

Comment: `memchr` can **efficiently** check a whole block for any non-zero bytes; a good libc implementation will use SIMD like it would for strlen.  Don't loop manually over bytes if you can avoid it; compilers don't optimize that well.

Answer (score 2):

You only check the first byte, then return one or zero immediately! If it is zero, as expected, you need to carry on to the next byte.

Try removing the two lines that say:

```
else
    return 0;
```

Then replace the final:

```
return 2;
```

with

```
return 0;
```

then your function will return zero if the entire block is zero and one if the block is non-zero.

Comment: why i can print out the 2nd byte if the if statement is omitted

Comment: Did this solve the problem for you? If so, could you please accept it as your answer. If not, please say what still doesn't work so I/someone else can assist further.